# records for sunday in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have to show records for employee for saturdays and sundays.how can i do this using  php.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res))
    { 
        list($name, $crd,$indate,$in,$out,$t) = $row;   
        $row[3] = date("g:i A", $in);
        $row[4] = date("g:i A" ,$out);
        $d3 = date("d-m-Y (D)", $in);
            $bg = '';
            if(date('D', $in) == 'Sun' || date('D', $in) == 'Sat')
                $bg = 'bgcolor=#EEEEEE';
                else 
                $bg = 'bgcolor= #ECE5B6';
                if ($ddate != $row[2] && $row[2] != null)
                {   
                    echo "<tr $bg><td colspan=4>Date: ".$d3."</td></tr>";
                    $ddate = $row[2];
                }
                else if($row[2]==null)
                {
                    $bg = 'bgcolor=#EEEEEE';
                    echo "<tr $bg><td colspan=4>Date: ".$from."</td></tr>";
                }

                if ($row[2] != null)
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td align=left width='35%'>".trim($name)."</td>";
                    echo "<td align=center width='20%' >".$row[3]."</td>";
                    echo "<td align=center  width='23%' >".$row[4]."</td>";
                    echo "<td align=center width='16%'>".$t."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }

                else
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td align=left width='35%'>".trim($name)."</td>";
                    echo "<td align=center width='20%' >Null</td>";
                    echo "<td align=center  width='23%' >Null</td>";
                    echo "<td align=center width='16%'>".$t."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }

            }
```

now the problem with this is for sunday all records are displayed  without date.

mysql is

```
SELECT mstEmp.empname, mstEmp.cardno, InDate, 
dailyattendance.InTime,dailyattendance.OutTime, mstEmp.teamtype 
FROM mstEmp 
LEFT JOIN dailyattendance
 ON (dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname )  
 AND (InDate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to') 
 WHERE (mstEmp.teamtype = '$chk') 
order by InDate DESC
```

i have this code which calls the above code

```
$sFrom = toYYYYMMDD($frm);
$sTo = toYYYYMMDD($t) . " 23:59:59";
while (strtotime($sFrom) <= strtotime($sTo)) 
{   
        setvalue($checkbox,$sFrom,$sFrom);
        $sFrom = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($sFrom)));
 }
```

Comment: Also, your data model is probably wrong. You seem to be storing date/time values as UNIX timestamps; this means that you'll get different results if you switch timezones on the server (so if someone works early on Monday in their own timezone, it might unintentionally read as late on Sunday when viewed in a different timezone) and you won't be able to store dates before 1970 (which is probably fine, unless you need to import really old legacy data).

Comment: everything is fine with this code the error in this is only that i getting records for each & every employee as null in the table but the date for sunday and saturday is not shown and if shown it is sumthing as 01-07-1970

Answer (score 0):

You should put DATE conditions in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT mstEmp.empname, mstEmp.cardno, InDate,  
dailyattendance.InTime,dailyattendance.OutTime, mstEmp.teamtype  
FROM mstEmp  
LEFT JOIN dailyattendance 
 ON (dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname )   
 WHERE (mstEmp.teamtype = '$chk')  AND (InDate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to')  
order by InDate DESC
```

Comment: it is not showing me null values for a particular day i.e it is not showing the absentees on a particular day